# C++ Warnings that points not to the code but to tuple, xmemory and utility

Tags: c++, warnings

I am trying to do book-keeping and cleaning my code.
I corrected all warning, but I cannot avoid following warning in xmemory, utility and tuple.
These particular warning points not to my code but to the source of C++.

Even it does that, does it mean that there is something wrong with my code?
Is there a possibility to know where in my code I cause these issues to happen.
If I double click to warnings they point me to these xmemory, utility and tuple files that I never changed.

Following is the screenshots of warnings that I try to resolve:
[image]

Comment: Show the source where `pair` is called. It looks like you made something like std::pair<int, int> and then want to construct it with values of type size_t, which possibly looses data.

Comment: It is a bit everywhere with wrong types, how to know exact lines that cause that?

Comment: Ask your IDE / compiler vendor. My compiler (gcc or clang) shows the error and a backtrace where it was called from.

Comment: What solved the issue is to got through Messaages, not warning messages. Indeed the problem was in tuples.